# Newbie and Can't log into Ubuntu after installation

Tags: boot, system-installation, login

I've just installed Ubuntu 14.04 LTS on my old Toshiba Satellite (L3000-248) which was previously running Windows Vista and which we've recently retired.  I wanted to try Linux and thought this was a good opportunity as it doesn't really matter if it all goes wrong.  I did it via USB using LinuxLive USB Creator and chose the option to erase everything and just install Ubuntu.  The installation seemed to go OK but after restarting the PC as directed I can't log into either my created profile or as a guest.  With my profile, it accepts the password but after about 10s it flashes to a black screen and then goes to the log in screen.  It's the same story with the guest profile but no password obviously.

I am a total newbie with this stuff, I'm not sure where to find the things you might need to help me but I CAN follow instructions so bear that in mind if you are nice enough to answer my post.

Thanks
Vicky

Thanks

Comment: Try going from login screen to the command line ( Ctrl + Alt + F2 ), and login there. If you can log in, run this command `ls -l $HOME/.Xauthority` . That is LS as in list and -L as in lion. It should say something like this `-rw------- 1 xieerqi xieerqi 150 Sep 26 09:04 /home/xieerqi/.Xauthority` . Sometimes that `.Xauthority` file will say `root root` which means by some accident, the file became owned by root and you cannot log in. Frequent problem. If that's not the case, we can try couple of other options. If that still doesn't work , you can reinstall it from scratch again.No harm there

Comment: if you reinstall, I suggest using either http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/ or you could burn the iso to a disk instead.

Comment: I can't login via the command line either, it just gives me a 'Login Incorrect' message (the login is correct).  I tried mounting the ISO on the usb using the software you suggested and reinstalled Ubuntu from scratch but I still can't get past the login screen.

Comment: Hi @Serg I've now decided to start again and installed the 15.04 version to see if that was any better.  I can now log in via the command line and I ran the ls -l $HOME/ .Xauthority command and all looked OK, no 'root  root' lines in there.

Comment: Is there anything else I could try?   I'm still stuck at the log in screen though and still can't sign in as a guest either.  The PC I'm using is pretty old (at least 6 years I reckon and it wasn't new when we bought it) so possibly that's the issue.  With all the problems I've had though I am really loath to try my luck with Ubuntu and the new laptop!

Comment: What type of gpu do you have

Answer (score 0):

It happened to me as well at one time. I re-booted the system and pressed ESC once, just before getting ready to load Ubuntu. I've seen somewhere they say to press SHIFT, but mine worked with the esc key. I chose Advanced options in the Grub Recovery menu. Chose something related to fixing broken packages. When done, I chose Failsafe mode VGA, then I rebooted. Did that again. Then I chose Normal boot. Once in Ubuntu,I logged in and it would take me back to login again. After the 3rd time it let me in. And then never presented that problem again, not even after rebooting later on.